# Concurrent jquery jsonp response being sent to wrong success handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have two jquery ajax methods that are firing off jsonp GET requests on page load. The form of the request methods are as follows:

```
function get_1(callback_method)
{
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url:url_endpoint_1,
    async: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    success: function(result) 
        {
            callback_method(result);
        },
    error: function(fail){ console.log(fail); }
    });

}

function get_2(callback_method)
{
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url:url_endpoint_2,
    async: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    success: function(result) 
        {
            callback_method(result);
        },
    error: function(fail){ console.log(fail); }
    });
}
```

When fired individually each method works perfectly. However when both are fired on page load the response to get_1 is sent to the get_2 success handler. What am I doing wrong?

### Edit 1

The callback_method is passed to the function. This is to abstract the call to the server because the same request is made for different reasons. For example

```
function alert_user(response)
{
    alert(response.text);
}

function log_to_console(response)
{
    console.log(response.text);
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    get_1(alert_user);
    get_2(log_to_console);
});
```

and elsewhere I may instead call

```
    get_1(log_to_console);
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions (i.e. what argument are you passing)? What does the `callback` function body look like?

Comment: Hi Rob. I've updated to the question to include an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jsonpCallback` option specifies the actual name of the callback that will handle the response for this request, **it should be unique**.

Quote from the [jQuery docs for the `jsonpCallback' option](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it
>   easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error
>   handling.

Don't confuse the `jsonpCallback` option with the `jsonp` option which sets the name of the param who's value is the generated callback name.

For example, if you set `jsonp: "callback"`, and leave out the `jsonpCallback` option [which you should], the resulting request will be something like `http://myUrl/.../?callback=jquery_123456789`, and the server's response will be `jquery_123456789(here_goes_the_response);` where `jquery_123456789` is a function generated by jQuery which will take care of passing the response to your success callback.

Comment: This is indeed the answer - together with the comment from oglu below. I've removed the jsonpCallback option and simply grabbed what JQuery sends to the server and wrapped the result in that for the response. Cheers :)